# Handling Strong and Weak entity types in a one-to-one relationship

Tags: database-design, schema, erd

I am modelling a database for a term project and I have come across something I do not have a definite answer to.

## Diagram

I was supplied with the following [Entity-Relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHvC8.jpg):

[image: Entity-Relationship diagram]

### Description

So, as you can see, such diagram depicts the following entity types:

- `District`, which has the attributes `Number`(set up as Primary Key), `Type` and `Description`.
- `Delegate`, that holds the attributes `Id` (defined as Primary Key), `Name`, `Sex` and `Description`.

Where `District` is the strong entity type supporting `Delegate`, but the cardinality of this relationship is **1:1**. Up to this point, I have seen **1:M** relationship cardinalities regarding strong/weak entities, and I know how to map those to tables, but in this case, I am not so sure, mainly because I do not know how I could get around the possibility of repeating `Delegates` if the `Delegate.Id` and the `District.Number` were to be a composite key.

## Questions

- What shall I do at the implementation level?
- Do I create a table to store `Delegate` instances, with the `Number` of the `District` as the only key?
- Is my understanding of composites key wrong?

Comment: Why deletate is a weak entity? Delegates seems entities of their own, that can be identified by their attributes alone, independently from the district.